# Route to internet via secondary wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

Is there any consumer wireless routers that would support the following: Main router, which I connect servers to via wire and provides wireless access. It is connected, by wire, to another router, provided by my ISP (Fios). Now, sometimes FIOS goes down, and what I would like to do, is to be able to route traffic from my local network, over to my neighbors wireless, which he gave me credentials for.

My current wireless router is an Asus 66U, and I dont see a way for it to both be a wireless router, as well as a client to connect to my neighbors ssid.

Is this even possible? Does one need special hardware? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is possible - definitely DD-WRT can act as a client and a AP for your network, so re-flashing your ASUS-66U with DD-WRT would be able to do it, However the DD-WRT page says about the ASUS-66U "it presents significant risk (bricking) " 
So this means your could be used but seems to dependg on some fireware versions

If you wished to purchase a new one check what is available at you local store - and look at the DD-WRT website to see if they are supported - I personally have a few models of TP-LINK wireless APs/modems which I have upgraded to DD-WRT - The models I have are all out of sale.

however be aware of the consideration about the router needing direct connection to the ISP or some sort of monitoring I mention lower.

Once that was done you then need to connect to the neighbor then reconfigure your routing to use both links , but the neighbor is at a lower priority
This involves adding two default routes to the router instead of just one , the route using the Wireless is added at a lower priority than the route via the fixed line - When the router sees that it can no longer reach the first gateway it will switch to the second gateway.

However there are a few considerations (besides the risk of bricking your router)

You need the failures of the ISP line to take the IP address off the router doing the decisions , however that will not be true if you have two routers in series as you describe.  To fix that you would need to connect the router making the decisions directly to the ISP line.  You may be able to setup some monitoring to check if the ISP is present - I don't know if DD-WRT is capable of this monitoring.

I believe the ASUS-66U is dual-band so that will help throughput if your neighbor can also support the second radio frequency - but DD-WRT can create a Client link and a link on the same band so this is not essential

Comment: Do you have a router that you would recommend that can act as a client and an AP?

Comment: I've updated the answer - ( I believe recommendations are off topic) the one you have would work - but you do need to understand what I was talking about the direct connection - This is what routing protocols do - but consume ADSL connectoions don't have that - so you need some sort of monitoring - I am a netork engineer so personally I have a Cisco router, and some other network stuff  so I've not looked at if DD-WRT can do this